# Angular 1.x bind to variable property

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to bind via html to a variable property in angular 1.x?

I have a data object that I need to update based on certain conditions, which would change the property it should bind to:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options">
    <custom-component selected="$ctrl.data[option.dataProperty]"></custom-component>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get it to bind into the `customComponent` with one or two way bindings. Would appreciate any other suggestions.

**Update:**

Thanks for the comments, writing the plunker illuminated the problem for me :) you can find it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zpe78BfIqUnZ9QDVHsYy?p=preview) for posterity's sake. Thanks!

Comment: Above should work. What problem you're getting.. Please elaborate your problem by adding directive and plunker/fiddle..

Comment: I agree with @PankajParkar, we need to at least see the directive to understand what is truly wrong.